# create code for both Selenium and Appium

Tags: c#, android, selenium, appium

I have a responsive web which I'm starting to create tests for with Selenium webdriver.
The thing is that I need to run my tests both on web and on Android mobile(AndroidDriver). 
what's the best way to build my page object classes in a way that changes will be minor in order to run the tests on a web on one hand and with appium on the other hand.
Cheers

Comment: my post was edited.  unfortunately ,it is not similar to the link shared

Comment: What have you tried and what was the result? Please read the help topics on [ask]. You need to research your own issue, find code samples, etc. and write your own code to solve the issue. If you do all that and still can't figure it out, then come back and edit your question and add notes from the research you did, the code you have tried reduced to a [mcve], and what the result was... any error messages, etc. It's also very important to include any relevant HTML and properly format the HTML and code.

Answer (score -1):

Please refer to the below link for the answer
[Using Selenium Webdriver Selectors in Appium ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38055234/using-selenium-webdriver-selectors-in-appium-ios)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Instead of posting an answer to a question that already exists, please flag the question as a duplicate or post the link as a comment. Also, link only answers are not permitted. If you are going to reference a link, please post the relevant parts here.

Comment: Thank you @JeffC, will follow that